# Error: unable to reflect System.web.configuration.machinekeySection with local iis

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, windows-7, iis-7.5, asp.net-3.5

I am running an ASP.net 3.5 web application with visual studio 2017. Everything working fine when I am running using **IIS express** but with classic pipeline. But I changed the settings (project properties – >Web – >Servers – > local iis; Created virtual directory as well) to run using **local iis** it is giving me the error "**unable to reflect System.web.configuration.machinekeySection**".
I am using IIS 7.5 and Windows 7

I tried creating the machine key (both validation and decryption key) in iis but the issue persists.

Does anyone have any idea?

Attaching the error description image here

[image]

Comment: It is an exception thrown from a custom framework, so you can only analyze its own code to review what might be wrong.

Comment: Still the issue is not resolved; Anyone have any workaround please